# Is it possible to make elements ignore the re-size of an element not using position:absolute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to know if there is a reasonably efficient way to make elements in a `<div>` ignore an element being re-sized next to them (by not moving with it) and the element is not `position:absolute`.  I thank anybody in advanced who is willing to help me!

Comment: Kinda, possibly, using `float`. But maybe not, depending on your situation. Can you add more info, maybe link to a JSfiddle with an example?

Comment: Examplesite1.co.nf is a great example, I would like any content under the animation to remain stationary throughout its playing.  Currently, it moves if placed below the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have properties you want the element to override you can try `!important` after the property.  It will make properties take precedence over parent elements, and many times you'll get the desired effect.  This is good if you need to apply a change quickly, but is not ideal.    Ideally, you'll have the parent set up to let the children flow from it.